# MakeFile: Implicit file declaration warnings in C

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

i am new to creating Make File and im running into some error caused by dependencies, basically in each "*.c" file i only include it self for example: Main will only include Main.h. As a result of this, i am trying to create the dependencies on MakeFile, the dependencies are:

-Main.c uses functions/structs that are declared in memory.h, synchronization.h, client.h, server.h proxy.h and process.h

-memory.c uses functions/structs that are declared in synchronization.h

-process.c uses functions/structs that are declared in client.h, proxy.h and server.h

Some other dependencies are made by `#include`  in the header files.

Some of the errors i have got so far are:

```
gcc -c process.c
process.c: In function ‘launch_process’:
process.c:25:46: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘execute_client’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             data->client_stats[process_id] = execute_client(process_id, buffers, data, sems);

process.c:30:45: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘execute_proxy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             data->proxy_stats[process_id] = execute_proxy(process_id, buffers, data, sems);

process.c:33:46: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘execute_server’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             data->server_stats[process_id] = execute_server(process_id, buffers, data, sems);

gcc -c main.c
main.c: In function ‘launch_processes’:
main.c:159:32: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘launch_process’; did you mean ‘launch_processes’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         data->client_pids[i] = launch_process(i, 0, buffers, data, sems);

main.c: In function ‘wait_processes’:
main.c:243:33: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘wait_process’; did you mean ‘wait_processes’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         data->client_stats[i] = wait_process(data->client_pids[i]); //o retorno dos processos client_pids etc ira returnar o return do execute_client sendo que sera o "exit" do processo
```

PS:I am not allowed to change header files and sorry for the long question by have spent more then 24 hours straight around this and this is not allowing me to test my finished project, Thank you.

Here is the makefile that i have created.

```
sovaccines: client.o proxy.o server.o process.o main.o memory.o  synchronization.o 
            gcc client.o proxy.o server.o process.o main.o memory.o  synchronization.o  -o sovaccines -lrt -pthread -g

main.o: main.c ../include/memory.h ../include/synchronization.h ../include/client.h ../include/proxy.h ../include/server.h ../include/process.h
            gcc -c main.c

client.o: client.c
            gcc -c client.c

memory.o: memory.c ../include/synchronization.h
            gcc -c memory.c 

process.o: process.c ../include/client.h ../include/proxy.h ../include/server.h
            gcc -c process.c

proxy.o: proxy.c
            gcc -c proxy.c

server.o: server.c
            gcc -c server.c

synchronization.o: synchronization.c 
            gcc -c synchronization.c
```

Comment: There are better ways of dealing with dependencies than hammering them out by hand in a `Makefile`. That's not sustainable. Look for [better templates to work from](https://makefiletutorial.com).

Comment: Why are you looking at your makefile dependencies for a solution to warnings issued by your compiler? I can see why you have had no luck finding a solution no matter how much time you spent barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @tadman So would it be a good idea to include all those header files into the main and the main?

Comment: Absolutely not. What I mean is there's tools that will generate dependency trees for you *automatically*. Writing this by hand is something that died off in the 1990s when such tools came to the forefront. You don't need to use something as complex as [CMake](https://cmake.org) but you *should* be using some of the basic tools that allow dependency tracking and clean builds without having to hammer out multiple lines *per file*.

Comment: It's worth noting that "implicit declaration" warnings should be treated as errors (`-Werror`) as it means you've missed a header file inclusion.

Comment: @tadman Totally agree with you about using something like (but not necessarily as complex) as `CMake` for this.  However, I guess the OP is doing a project for school and if he's being asked to use `Make` by hand, then that's the assignment.  Doing it a better way may not be allowed by the instructor...

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem related to `Makefile`, actually.  It's about your C code and what header files you are or are not including.  Once you have those correctly, then you can insert them into your `Makefile` and it will be fine.  You do not need to change header files; but the number or order you include them is what you're doing wrong.  Make sure you include them in `main.c` and `process.c` so that functions are defined before being used...

Comment: @Ray Yes that´s excactly the case, either way im trying to see things like automake, etc and see if i can do it

Comment: @Ray I am going to try that aswell, it makes more sense, that´s what i had at the beginning but i really tought all of this should have been kept into the make file, Thanks

Comment: @ray The nice thing about some tools is that you can use them and they just stamp out plain old `Makefile` data, so *nobody has to know*.

Comment: When using a `Makefile` the usual goal is to set it up once and make as few changes as possible to it over time so that you don't break the build. There's a multitude of templates out there to work from, some kind of inefficient but super simple, some far more efficient but more difficult to understand, but all of them help you save time and avoid silly mistakes caused by your dependency listing being incorrect or out of date. There's nothing worse than fixing a bug, rebuilding, only to find it's still there, realizing hours later it was because of dependency errors it didn't really build.

Comment: @tadman Hmmmm, I don't know...  A good marker who knows these tools him/herself will notice what wasn't done by hand.  In the "real world", we should absolutely do it better -- but we often forget that when we first learned it, we did it an inefficient way to learn.  The learning process is absolutely not the "real world"...  For example, the point of assignment 1 might be to teach an inefficient way and the follow-up assignment might be to do it better to appreciate it more.  Generally, totally agree with you; just saying there might be a whole learning process planned that we don't know.

Comment: If you're (Bruno) still stuck, you should post snippets of your `main.c` and what you're including.  But having had these type of problems many times in my career, I find leaving the computer and going for a walk to help.  Then sit back down and write out on paper what depends on what.  Assuming you have no circular dependencies (!!!), it should become clear.  Sorry, more personal advice and not really technical advice!  Good luck!

Comment: @Ray Finally i followed all of ur guys tips, combined them all and finally made it, i have created a Auto dependency tracker with some help of tuturials and i think i have got it right, and included the headers that i needed, now the code is running and just had some minor bugs Thank you all !!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working!  Indeed, there are now excellent tools to do what you're doing.  But haven't had to go through what you're going through, I do understand (now...I didn't back then...) that some teachers want you/us to struggle in the beginning to better appreciate what the tools do for us...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your warnings simply tell you that you forgot to include the correct header files in your C source files, or that you did not tell the compiler where to find these header files. Example: if in `main.c` you have something like:

```
#include "memory.h"
#include "synchronization.h"
#include "client.h"
#include "server.h"
#include "proxy.h"
#include "process.h"
```

you should pass the `-I../include` option to `gcc`. As you are using GNU make your Makefile could then look like this:

```
SRC     := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ     := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
INCLUDE := ../include
CFLAGS  := -g -I$(INCLUDE)
LDLIBS  := -lrt -pthread
VPATH   := $(INCLUDE)

sovaccines: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

main.o: memory.h synchronization.h client.h proxy.h server.h process.h
memory.o: synchronization.h
process.o: client.h proxy.h server.h

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

- [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function) and [`patsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) are make functions
- `CC`, `CFLAGS`, `LDLIBS`... are [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables)
- `VPATH` defines a [Search Path for All Prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search)
- `$@`, `$^`, `$<`... are [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables)
- `%.o: %.c` is a [Pattern Rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules)

Note that there are ways to automatically generate the dependencies of source files on header files. If you are interested, have a look, for example, at this excellent guide: [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

Note also that make knows already how to compile and link C projects. It has [Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules). This is another way to further simplify your Makefile. In the proposed Makefile above you could, for instance, omit the pattern rule completely and also the recipe of the `sovaccines: $(OBJ)` rule.